# How configure OAuth 2.0 Loopback Interface Redirection for Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, oauth-2.0

For native applications, [OAuth 2.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.3) allows to use plain "http" redirect URIs with variable ports. At least on `https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/view`, a configuration like `http://127.0.0.1/oauth` will not be accepted. Is there any other way to configure a localhost loopback redirect URI?